# Finding all subspaces of $F_2^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $F_2$ be the field with $2$ elements. List all subspaces of $F_2^2$ and prove the list is complete.

So, we have the vectors $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$. So we have maximal $4$ subspaces, which ones are subspaces ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you been able to find any subspaces?

Comment: Hint: apart from the trivial subspaces consider $\{(0,0), (1,0)\}$. See if this satisfies the requirements of a subspace.

Comment: Why a maximum of $4$? With $4$ vectors, I'd expect a maximum of $2^4$ subspaces, one for each subset of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\dim \Bbb F_2^2=2$. Thus every nontrivial subspace has dimension one. These are given by $\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}$
\begin{align*}
\Span\{(0,1)\} &=\{(0,0),(0,1)\} & \Span\{(1,0)\} &= \{(0,0),(1,0)\} &
\Span\{(1,1)\} &= \{(0,0),(1,1)\}
\end{align*}